# How to Insert Pandas Variable in Python email using win32com

Tags: python, pandas, outlook, win32com

Hi I am using the following code along with Pandas and Numpy

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'mail@domain.com'
mail.Subject = 'Test'
mail.Body = 'Message body'
mail.HTMLBody = '<html>............................</html>'
 #this field is optional

# To attach a file to the email (optional):
#attachment  = "Path to the attachment"
#mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)

mail.Send()
```

In the html body I would like to use some of the values from pandas like df.shape[0] or df['column'].max() or even variable1 = df['column'].max()

How can i achieve this in in the above code , I intend to use those values from Pandas in HTML message to Outlook.

Comment: So add them into the html. It's not clear to me what your sticking point is. The html is just a string and you want to format values into that string.

Comment: If at a place in html i add like df['name'].max() it is not readable and throws error.

Comment: Which is why you would use `.format()`. You've buried yourself in the specifics of the problem; the requirement is simply to format values into a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body of the email is a string, so you can simply use [`format`](https://pyformat.info) and substitute any variable, for instance:

```
mail.HTMLBody = '<html>........variable1 is: {v}....</html>'.format(v=variable1)
```